# How to copy an event listener in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-listener

So I am making some overrides on a Wordpress plugin. I need to copy the event listener on an element and then replace the element and add it back. The event listener is generated by the plugin.

I thought getEventListeners() would work but I have read that it only works in console. If that is this case I'm really astounded. We're in freaking 2020 and I am not finding an obvious solution to this.

What is the solution here people?

Below is the code I was trying to implement having assumed getEventListeners wasn't just a console function.

```
  // Edit Affirm
  (function replaceAffirm() {
    if (document.querySelector(".affirm-modal-trigger")) {
      const learnMore = document.querySelector("#learn-more");
      const modalTrigger = document.querySelector(".affirm-modal-trigger");
      const clickHandler = getEventListeners(modalTrigger).click[0].listener;
      const substr = learnMore.innerHTML
        .toString()
        .substring(
          learnMore.innerHTML.indexOf("h") + 2,
          learnMore.innerHTML.length
        );
      learnMore.innerHTML = "Easy Financing with " + substr;
      modalTrigger.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        replaceAffirm();
      }, 250);
    }
  })();
```

HTML

```
<p id="learn-more" class="affirm-as-low-as" data-amount="20000" data-affirm-color="white" data-learnmore-show="true" data-page-type="product">
   Starting at 
   <span class="affirm-ala-price">$68</span>
   /mo with 
   <span class="__affirm-logo __affirm-logo-white __ligature__affirm_full_logo__ __processed">Affirm</span>. 
   <a class="affirm-modal-trigger" aria-label="Prequalify Now (opens in modal)" href="javascript:void(0)">Prequalify now</a>
</p>
```

Comment: might be useful https://gist.github.com/dmnsgn/36b26dfcd7695d02de77f5342b0979c7

Comment: As far as I can tell, that function is *Chrome* only, not console only. Anyway, you can remove the element, then add it back somewhere else instead. Also, please add the relevant HTML code

Comment: What you're doing just seems like you're thinking about your problem wrong. What exactly is it that you're trying to do with the string manipulation? And why does it have to happen every 250 milliseconds?

Comment: Because the plugin loads in html elements and it takes time so I need to check when the element is loaded in the DOM and then edit it. I am removing elements in a P tag that has other span elements inside but also just has text which is super annoying because I cant edit it all via .children

Comment: Please add your html code for better understanding.

Comment: I'll have to add an answer later. Don't edit the innerHTML. Probably the best way is to edit the textContent. It'll keep the event listener.

Comment: The event listeners is attached to some of the content in the textContent.  textContent = "Starting at $68/mo with Affirm. Prequalify now"... the event lsitener is on the Prequalify now.

Comment: Text cannot have an event listener on it.

Comment: Right right sure if you want to get technical its on the a tag. Any best solution advise for copying event listeners with vanilla js? Editing the textContent as you propose will not work in the given situation.

Comment: I'll give it to you straight. You cannot copy event handlers in vanilla JS. At all. It's not a thing that's available to you because it simply isn't possible in vanilla JS. An event handler is blackboxed once it's added unless there's an external reference. However, there is likely a way to get the end result of what you want, you're just looking in the wrong direction for a solution. I'll take a look in 10 minutes and try to help.

Comment: Okay thanks man. I think its freaking crazy we're in 2020 and there is no plain JS solution to copy event listeners. Is it blackboxed for security?

Comment: @MichaelPaccione Theoretically it could be for security, but more likely it was just forced into that state by design. Several libraries like JQuery implement there own event listener proxy object so that you can manage events better. I added an answer, but let me know if it's not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy event listeners, but it seems because of the structure of your HTML it's more likely that you shouldn't need to re-add it. Instead of editing the HTML and removing the event listener by doing so, the best bet would be to edit around it.

If you want to remove the text nodes you can iterate through `childNodes` and separate out what should be removed.

Then to rebuild the appropriate text where you want it you can use `insertAdjacentText`

```js
if (document.querySelector(".affirm-modal-trigger")) {
  const learnMore = document.querySelector("#learn-more");
  const modalTrigger = document.querySelector(".affirm-modal-trigger");
  const children = Array.from(learnMore.childNodes);

  children.forEach(child => {
    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE || child.matches(".affirm-ala-price")) {
      if (learnMore.contains(child)) {
        learnMore.removeChild(child);
      }
    }
  });

  learnMore.insertAdjacentText("afterBegin", "Easy Financing With ");
  modalTrigger.insertAdjacentText("beforeBegin", " ");
} else {
  setTimeout(function() {
    replaceAffirm();
  }, 250);
}
```

```html
<p id="learn-more" class="affirm-as-low-as" data-amount="20000" data-affirm-color="white" data-learnmore-show="true" data-page-type="product">
  Starting at
  <span class="affirm-ala-price">$68</span> /mo with
  <span class="__affirm-logo __affirm-logo-white __ligature__affirm_full_logo__ __processed">Affirm</span>.
  <a class="affirm-modal-trigger" aria-label="Prequalify Now (opens in modal)" href="javascript:void(0)">Prequalify now</a>
</p>
```

Comment: insertAdjacentText !!! Awesome, I did not know of this function :) I will give this a test later tonight. Replacing the entire textContent of course removes the event listener so hopefully this method is just an insert and not a replace under the hood. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelPaccione I would say it is, unfortunately, not as well known as it should be. It's incredibly useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes waiting for the Html element to be loaded and checking until it gets loaded is okay and this is one of the correct ways to wait for it.

As per my understanding of your issue, you just have to change the text of the learn-more element. 
for that, it is not necessary to copy event listener and then again binding it.

Instead of replacing the whole element just change the text keeping the same element.
So it gets binded with the event listener by default.

Comment: Hi Minal I have added the HTML. The question is how to copy the event listeners on the affirm-modal-trigger, save it into a variable, then add it back to the newly edited DOM elements. When you reset the innerHTML the Event Listeners on elements are lost.

Comment: Also using the textContent method does not work because the element that has the event listener on it is in the textContent. Naturally replacing the textContent as with innerHTML removes the listener.